# Adding Regex Authorization domains in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

During my e2e tests, the deployment of the site happens on a custom domain, for example if I hold the domain as:

`https://example.net`

then during the E2E testing the deployment happens as:

`https://<some-random-deployment-id>.dev.example.net`

Now for most of the tests, I would be mocking firebase services, however, for some specific tests, I need firebase services to be enabled. I want to know if it's possible to supply a regex since the deployment id would change after each deployment?

I would like to input something like: `^https://dev\.example\.net/.*$` in authorized domains.

[image]